# How to draw rounded image with text in HTML Canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to draw image with rounded shape and the text on the bottom. But when I use `ctx.clip()` to round image corners, text dissappears.
Text with rectangle image works fine but I need images cornes to be rounded.

```js
 ctx.save();
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(100, 100, 100, 0.8)`;
 ctx.arc(x, y, z / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 ctx.clip();
 ctx.drawImage(img.img, x - 10, y - 10, 20, 20);
 ctx.fill();
 ctx.font = `${3.5}px Arial`;
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.textAlign = "center";
 ctx.fillText('TEXT', x, y + 13.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a workable code it’s hard to t/s. I think you just need to restore after `ctx.fill()` though.

```
ctx.save();
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(100, 100, 100, 0.8)`;
 ctx.arc(x, y, z / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 ctx.clip();
 ctx.drawImage(img.img, x - 10, y - 10, 20, 20);
 ctx.fill();
 ctx.restore(); //add this
 ctx.font = `${3.5}px Arial`;
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.textAlign = "center";
 ctx.fillText('TEXT', x, y + 13.5);
```